# Как сделать так чтобы страница на всех платформах загружалась в версии для ПК?

Tags: html, android, css, html5, meta

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда интерактивный элемент корректно отображается на ПК и не корректно на андроид.
Элемент - wasm macrosquad, и это его недоработка.

Как сделать так чтобы страница на всех платформах загружалась как на ПК?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `Как сделать так чтобы страница на всех платформах загружалась как на ПК?` вытащите его свойства из `@media desctop` в `:root` при этом заданные для него в остальных `@media` удалите(закоментируйте, ради избежания ошибок типа "удалил не то"). если надо проще, откройте сайт на десктопе, кликните на нужном элементе "исследовать", там в инспекторе смотрите css -> вычислено. оттуда все скопируйте с импортантами в самый конец css файла. всё.